# MoonMail Missing recipients using createRecipient endpoint

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, moonmail

I created 5,000 recipients in a list. These emails were `success+{uniqueInt}@simulator.amazonses.com` and `bounce+{uniqueInt}@simulator.amazonses.com`.

For some unknown reason, only 4,135 emails were added. I found this using:

`aws dynamodb scan --table-name XXX-sentEmails --select "COUNT"`

I found no exceptions in the logs:

```
aws logs filter-log-events
        --log-group-name /aws/lambda/XX-createRecipient
        --filter-pattern Exception
        --output text
```

Any ideas what could happens? Can DynamoDB reject records silently?

Comment: Do you have any duplicate hash key data in the data set? DynamoDB API (put Item) updates the item if it finds the hash key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because either you had duplicated emails or you run out of write capacity in DynamoDB. If you're using the `createRecipient` endpoint, then you're saving items one by one, which leads to a waste of DynamoDB resources. Try to import in bulk instead

Comment: This is exactly what I did: https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail/pull/244